# Use RxJs operators on Array

Tags: arrays, linq, rxjs, rxjs5

I do know that RxJs `observables` are async collections that yield over time when the `Observable` is being subscribed.

Now I would like to use RxJs operators as Linq operators. My question is how can I use the RxJs operators on `Array` instead of `Observables`.

For example I would like to know how many instances matches of an `Array` collection matches a specific filter:

```
let countMatchingMembers = (collection: Array<any>): number => {
    // I want to use on collection instead of Rx.Observable
    const matchingMembersObservable = Rx.Observable.from(collection) 
      .filter(p => {
        return p.value !== null && typeof p.value !== "undefined";
      });

    return matchingMembersObservable.count() > 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot use them for arrays, since they are not defined for arrays. PS: for this very example js arrays already have built-in `filter` and `length`.

Comment: I know arrays do have functions, but I am asking as a general question as I would like to use more advanced operators like join, flatmap, distinct. I know there are some Linq libraries but I was hoping to do that with one and unique library.

Comment: So convert an array to an observable with `Rx.Observable.from()`? Any problem with that?

Comment: I want to use the operators to return the result synchronously.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is large misunderstanding of what what RxJS is. RxJS let's you use Linq-like syntax to chain operators. RxJS underneath in fact just subscribes Observables to Observers, operators don't return values directly like array functions such as `Array.map()`. This means everything in RxJS (and all Reactive Extension implementations) is asynchronous.

Your example could be written like:

```
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';

Observable.from([4,5,9,2,7])
  .filter(val => val > 5)
  .count()
  .subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Which prints to console:

```
2
```

See live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/6IneUursxrdpLYAo6P2v

If you're about to use RxJS 5 then I recommend you to read the doc that is currently available only on their github page: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/doc

Comment: Hello Martin, I do understand that Observable are async and cannot be used for sync operation. I was wondering if the RxJs team was offering the same operators for arrays and sync operations. Do you know any library like `collectionsjs` that allow to do that and provide typescript support.

Comment: No, this is not event a purpose of RxJS, You'll probably need to look for some other library in your situation. I don't have any experience with `collectionsjs` though.

Answer (score 1):

As [Martin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39954198/434227) this is not what Observables are for. Observables are there to implement a push system for (multiple) values asynchronously.

But let's ignore their real purpose for a second. Of course it is technically possible to do whatever you want with Observables. 
To deal with their async nature I wrapped one Observable in a Promise in the example below. This gives me an easy way to return one value(!) after using all the Operators that I like on some dataset. By using the `then` function of the Promise I can create kind of a synchronous flow.

```
const array = [1,2,3,4,5];
const promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    Rx.Observable.from(array)
      .filter(x => x % 2 === 0)
      .reduce((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
      .subscribe(next => resolve(next));
  });

promise
  .then(result => console.log(result));
```

[jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fetase/edit?js,console)

Using `async`/`await` (as soon as it is standardised) I guess this could also be written in a really synchronous way.

But again, this is more like an experiment. I wouldn't use it in production code.